# Insertar en Registro y en el Detalle de ese Registro PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Estoy tratando que ingresar ciertos registros que estan en una tabla "Eventos" y dentro de ese evento estoy registrando personas (estando asi la tabla "Personas" que participan en ese evento, para ello tengo una tabla "Detalle Evento" para así al insertar ese Evento puedo observar todos las personas que se registraron en ese evento.

Para ello tengo una relación de muchos a muchos, que se parte en la tabla "Detalle Evento". Sin embargo mi duda es al momento de hacer el insert. El Insert del Evento lo hace correctamente, pero no es el caso para el del Detalle, donde no logro entender la logica para hacerlo. Investigando he realizado lo siguiente sin lograr el objetivo:

[image: La base de datos. tab_jef = "Personas" y tab_reg="Evento"]

Y este es el codigo donde estoy guardando ese evento junto a su detalle.

```
<?php 

include "../paginas/conexion.php";

$nombr_reg = $_POST['nombr_reg'];
$descr_reg = $_POST['descr_reg'];
$fecre_reg = $_POST['fecre_reg'];

$jefes = array($_POST['ident_jef']);

$ident_ref = 1;
$statu_reg = 1;


    $query_insert = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg,descr_reg,fecre_reg,statu_reg) VALUES('$nombr_reg','$descr_reg','$fecre_reg','$statu_reg')");

    if ($query_insert) {

        foreach ($_POST['ident_jef'] as $jefes) {
        $query_insert_det = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg,ident_jef) VALUES('$ident_reg','$ident_jef')");
    }

     }

header('location: ../paginas/registro_registro_exito.php');
?>
```

[image: El Formulario del Registro del Evento]

Parte del Formulario donde selecciono las personas a ser agregadas en el evento:

```
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="col form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="ident_jef"><b>Familias: </b></label>
          <?php 
            $query_jef = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tab_jef");
            $result_jef = mysqli_num_rows($query_jef);
          ?>
          <select class="selectpicker" id="ident_jef" name="ident_jef" data-live-search="true" multiple>
            <?php 
              if ($result_jef > 0) {
              while ($jef = mysqli_fetch_array($query_jef)) {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $jef['ident_jef'];?>"><?php echo $jef['ident_jef'];?> - <?php echo $jef['cedul_jef'];?> - <?php echo $jef['nombr_jef'];?> <?php echo $jef['apeli_jef'];?></option>
            <?php
            }
            }
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Te da algun error?

Comment: Ningun error. El problema es que no registra en el Detalle del Evento las personas que seleccione. Ya voy a anexar el formulario.

Comment: De entrada te falta recuperar el `tab_reg.ident_reg` después de insertar en `tab_reg`. Lo obtienes con `mysqli_insert_id()`, asumiendo que dicha columna tiene `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Sí, es Auto Increment. Como aplicaría eso que me dices?

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil ver el problema sin poder replicarlo, sin embargo, en tu código no veo donde has definido las variables `$ident_reg` y `$ident_jef`. Asumo tambien que la variable `$conexion` esta definida en el fichero `pagina/conexion.php`.

Asumiré algo así:

```
<?php

include "../paginas/conexion.php";

$nombr_reg = $_POST['nombr_reg'];
$descr_reg = $_POST['descr_reg'];
$fecre_reg = $_POST['fecre_reg'];

$ident_ref = 1;
$statu_reg = 1;


$query_insert = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg,descr_reg,fecre_reg,statu_reg) VALUES('$nombr_reg','$descr_reg','$fecre_reg','$statu_reg')");

$ident_reg = mysqli_insert_id(conexion);
if ($query_insert) {

    foreach ($_POST['ident_jef'] as $ident_jef) {
        $query_insert_det = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg,ident_jef) VALUES('$ident_reg','$ident_jef')");
    }

}

header('location: ../paginas/registro_registro_exito.php');
```

Quizás podrías refactorizar un poco y evitar el uso de abreviaturas:

> "Siempre escribe tu código como si la persona que va a terminar manteniéndolo fuera un psicópata violento que sabe donde vives" -- *Sabio dicho popular*

```
<?php

include "../paginas/conexion.php";

$record_name = $_POST['nombr_reg'];
$record_description = $_POST['descr_reg'];
$record_date = $_POST['fecre_reg'];
$record_status = 1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg,descr_reg,fecre_reg,statu_reg) VALUES('$record_name','$record_description','$record_date','$record_status')";

/** @var mysqli $conexion */
$query_insert = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$record_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

if ($query_insert) {
    foreach ($_POST['ident_jef'] as $boss_id) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg,ident_jef) VALUES('$record_id','$boss_id')";
        $query_insert_det = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    }
}

header('location: ../paginas/registro_registro_exito.php');
```

Comment: Como esta planteado parece tener lógica, sin embargo no logro todavia insertar esos datos... Actualice el tema con parte del formulario donde selecciono las "Personas"

Comment: Sería bueno que usaras una herramienta como xdebug para que identifiques donde exactamente se quiebra tu código, ten en cuenta que los detalles solo se insertan si la primera query que ejecutas fue exitoso, deberías verificar si al menos el primer query se ejecuta con exito.

Comment: Renombrar no es refactorizar, ¿Qué ganas cambiando ident_jef por boss_id? Son practicamente igual de crípticos, pero tu lo propones en inglés, lo que lo hace peor a ojos de SO en español.

Comment: @Sal nunca dije que renombrar fuese refactorizar (Aunque este dentro de sus acciones), mencione no usar abreviaciones en lo posible y bien pude haber escrito $jefe_id, $descripción_registro, $nombre_registro y hubiese estado bien, lo escribí en ingles solo por alguna preferencia que he tomado últimamente. No creo que SO en español fomente escribir netamente en nuestra lengua así que no distorsione la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo tu problema como lo siguiente.

Agrego un registro que puede tener muchos detalles, y estos detalles pueden pertenecer a muchos jefes.

**Caso 1. Agregar un registro y le agregas un detalle.**

---

Si este es el caso tienes que agregar un registro, este registro tiene que llevar un id con el que lo logres identificar, en este caso será el registro_id con valor uno. En este caso quieres agregar el detalle y asociarlo con el registro, entonces para relacionarlos guardas el detalle con el registro_id con valor uno, y la información del detalle.

```
$query_insert = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg,descr_reg,fecre_reg,statu_reg) VALUES('$nombr_reg','$descr_reg','$fecre_reg','$statu_reg')");
$record_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg,ident_jef) VALUES('$record_id','$boss_id')";);
```

Espero te ayude de algo.

Answer (score 0):

en la vista, probaría eliminando la clase del datepicker del select, es decir, dejar solo esto:

```
<select id="ident_jef" name="ident_jef" multiple>
...
</select>
```

Luego, cuando se haga el post, deberás obtener el id del registro insertado en la tabla "tab_reg" y usarlo en el foreach:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO tab_reg(nombr_reg, descr_reg, fecre_reg, statu_reg) VALUES ('$nombr_reg', '$descr_reg', '$fecre_reg', '$statu_reg') ");

$ident_reg = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

if ($query && $ident_reg > 0) {
    foreach ($_POST['ident_jef'] as $ident_jef) 
        mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg,ident_jef) VALUES ('$ident_reg','$ident_jef')");
}
```

Por otra parte y muy importante, **tu código es vulnerable a [inyecciones sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)**, deberías evitar y dejar de usar las variables directamente en las querys. Por ejemplo, imagina que alguien introduce el siguiente código como valor del "ident_jef":

```
'); DELETE FROM det_reg; --
```

La query resultante dentro del foreach sería:

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO det_reg(ident_reg,ident_jef) VALUES ('$ident_reg',''); DELETE FROM det_reg; --')");
```

Comment: He probado pero todavía nada... "ident_jef" no tendría que como convertirse en un array o algo similar? al tratarse de varios id's que pudiera traerse.

Comment: Vale, ¿puedes hacer un var_dump de $ident_reg antes del If y de $ident_jef dentro del foreach ? para ver si efectivamente  $ident_reg y $ident_jef tienen valores